# Is there a difference when using brackets in include & require?

Tags: php, require, php-include

When using `include`/`include_once` and `require`/`require_once`, the [PHP docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php) show examples as such:

```
include 'filename.php';
```

And also on the same page, users have contributed examples looking like this:

```
include ('filename.php');
```

As far as I can see, the PHP docs do not mention the required use of brackets, or even any ability to include them. Do the brackets make a difference to how the function works?

Comment: No, there isn't any different. Just a matter of taste.

Comment: If you read your page further: `Because include is a special language construct, parentheses are not needed around its argument. Take care when comparing return value. `

Comment: @AndréFerraz It turns out there is a difference, as noted by the other commenter.

Comment: @Lee yes but in the example you provided there is no difference.